# Can I mix in AngularJS in fields added by link_to_add_assocation via Cocoon gem in Rails 4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, ruby-on-rails-4, formtastic, cocoon-gem

So I am using the link_to_add_association helper to dynamically add form fields in a Rails 4 application.  I initially thought I could mix in AngularJS as follows:

***this is a haml code template (formtastic gem) of what will be added via cocoon***

```
= f.inputs do
  = f.input :funding_type, label: "Kite type", as: :select, collection: ["yes", "no", "maybe"], input_html: { "ng-model" => "data", "ng-change" => "update()", "data-ng-options" => "kiteType in data"  }
```

Instead, I get escaped html similar to:

```
&lt;li class=&quot;select input optional&quot; id=&quot;person_kite_submissions_attributes_new_kite_submissions_funding_type_input&quot;&gt;&lt;label for=&quot;person_kite_submissions_attributes_new_kite_submissions_funding_type&quot; class=&quot;label&quot;&gt;Funding type&lt;/label&gt;&lt;select name=&quot;person[kite_submissions_attributes][new_kite_submissions][funding_type]&quot; id=&quot;person_kite_submissions_attributes_new_kite_submissions_funding_type&quot; class=&quot;kite_submission_dropdown&quot; ng-model=&quot;kiteSubmission.fundingType&quot; ng-change=&quot;update()&quot; data-ng-options=&quot;fundingType in kiteSubmission.fundingType&quot;&gt;&lt;option value=&quot;&quot;&gt;&lt;/option&gt;
                  &lt;option value=&quot;Red&quot;&gt;Red&lt;/option&gt;
                  &lt;option value=&quot;Blue&quot;&gt;Blue&lt;/option&gt;
                  &lt;option value=&quot;Green&quot;&gt;Green&lt;/option&gt;&lt;/select&gt;
```

So then I think Angular will not be able to pick up on the DOM injections since the cocoon (or possibly formtastic gem) gem is escaping the html string.

Am I better off just ripping out the cocoon gem and using straight Angular?  Or what would be a good approach.  It's only when I view source in Chrome that I noticed this, inspecting the element yielded proper looking html code which is why it took me a couple of hours to notice this.